# Custom Registration username_exists / email_exists

Tags: php, plugin-development, customization, user-registration

(1st post)

I have built a custom registration form for my Wordpress site and even though it has complete functionality, I am getting validation errors for both username_exists and email_exists.

This is what happens:

If I fill out the registration form with any mistakes, it doesn't register and it produces the correct errors.

If I fill out the registration form with no mistakes (AND a unique username and email), it registers correctly and inserts the userdata. But it still produces the username_exists and email_exists errors.

I've been wrestling with this for weeks now and haven't been able to come up with a solution. I'll be glad to provide the code if needed.

Thank you!

(main plugin code - sorry if not formatted right. Still getting used to the forum)

```
function slyd_register() {
    wp_enqueue_style('slyd-register', plugins_url('/css/sr-styles.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slyd_register', plugins_url( '/js/sr-scripts.js', __FILE__ ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','slyd_register');


/////////////////
// PLUGIN CORE //
/////////////////

function cr(&$fields, &$errors) {
  // Check args and replace if necessary
  if (!is_array($fields))     $fields = array();
  if (!is_wp_error($errors))  $errors = new WP_Error;

  // Check for form submit
  if (isset($_POST['reg_submit'])) {
    // Get fields from submitted form
    $fields = cr_get_fields();
    // Validate fields and produce errors
    if (cr_validate($fields, $errors)) {
      // If successful, register user
      wp_insert_user($fields);

            echo '';
            echo 'Registration complete. Please Login';
            echo '';
      // Clear field data
      $fields = array(); 
        }
  }

  // Santitize fields
  cr_sanitize($fields);
  // Generate form
  cr_display_form($fields, $errors);
}

function cr_sanitize(&$fields) {
    $fields['user_role']    =  isset($fields['user_role'])  ? sanitize_text_field($fields['user_role']) : '';
  $fields['user_login']   =  isset($fields['user_login'])  ? sanitize_user($fields['user_login']) : '';
  $fields['user_email']   =  isset($fields['user_email'])  ? sanitize_email($fields['user_email']) : '';
    $fields['user_pass']    =  isset($fields['user_pass'])   ? esc_attr($fields['user_pass']) : '';
    $fields['user_pass2']   =  isset($fields['user_pass2'])   ? esc_attr($fields['user_pass2']) : '';
  $fields['first_name']   =  isset($fields['first_name'])  ? sanitize_text_field($fields['first_name']) : '';
  $fields['last_name']    =  isset($fields['last_name'])  ? sanitize_text_field($fields['last_name']) : '';
  $fields['nickname']     =  isset($fields['nickname'])  ? sanitize_text_field($fields['nickname']) : '';
}


function cr_display_form($fields = array(), $errors = null) {
  // Check for wp error obj and see if it has any errors  
  if (is_wp_error($errors) && count($errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
    // Display errors
    foreach ($errors->get_error_messages() as $key=>$val) {
            echo '';
            echo '' . $val . '';
            echo '';
    }
  }

        global $wp_roles;

        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
?>
     (MAIN FORM HERE)

  $_POST['user_role'],
    'user_login'    =>  $_POST['user_login'],
    'user_email'    =>  $_POST['user_email'],
    'user_pass'     =>  $_POST['user_pass'],
        'user_pass2'    =>  $_POST['user_pass2'],
    'first_name'    =>  $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name'     =>  $_POST['last_name'],
    'nickname'      =>  $_POST['nickname']
  );
}


function cr_validate(&$fields, &$errors) {
  // Make sure there is a proper wp error obj
  // If not, make one
  if (!is_wp_error($errors))  $errors = new WP_Error;

//role
        if ( empty( $fields['user_role'] ) || ! empty( $fields['user_role'] ) && trim( $fields['user_role'] ) == '' ) {
            $errors->add('role','ERROR: You must include a plan');
        }
//make sure fields are not empty
        $fieldVal = array($fields['user_email'], $fields['first_name'], $fields['last_name'], $fields['nickname']);
        if (in_array('',$fieldVal)) {
            $errors->add('field', 'Missing Entry: All fields are required');
        }
//username
        if (strlen($fields['user_login']) add('username_length', 'Username too short. At least 4 characters are required');
        }
        if (username_exists($fields['user_login'])) {
        $errors->add('user_name', 'The username is already in use');
        }
        if (!validate_username($fields['user_login'])) {
            $errors->add('username_invalid', 'Sorry, the username you entered is not valid');
        }
//email 
        if (!is_email($fields['user_email'])) {
            $errors->add('email_invalid', 'This is not a valid email address');
        }
        if (email_exists($fields['user_email'])) {
            $errors->add('email', 'This email address has already been used');
        }
//password
        if (strlen($fields['user_pass']) add('password', 'Password must be 8 or more characters');
        }
        if (isset($fields['user_pass']) && $fields['user_pass'] != $fields['user_pass2'] ) {
            $errors->add('password_reset_mismatch', 'The passwords do not match');
        }
// If errors were produced, fail
        if (count($errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
            return false;
        }

// Else, success!
  return true;
}


///////////////
// SHORTCODE //
///////////////

// The callback function for the [cr] shortcode
function reg_shortcode() {
  $fields = array();
  $errors = new WP_Error();
  // Buffer output
  ob_start();
  // Custom registration, go!
  cr($fields, $errors);
  // Return buffer
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('ss_registration_form', 'reg_shortcode');
```

Comment: Probably your logic calls those functions even after inserting the user? "I'll be glad to provide the code if needed" that would be helpful.

Comment: I've added the code above.

Answer (score 1):

[Resolved] - It turns out the issue was a conflict with the Yoast SEO plugin. Yoast was re-sending the headers after the user was registered. So the errors were re-checked and the username_exists / email_exists showed up as duplicates. I was able to get around this by disabling Yoast just for the registration page with a code hack in the functions file.

If you run into this issue, here's the code:

```
add_action('template_redirect','remove_wpseo');

function remove_wpseo(){
    if (is_page(5526)) {
        global $wpseo_front;
            if(defined($wpseo_front)){
                remove_action('wp_head',array($wpseo_front,'head'),1);
            }
            else {
              $wp_thing = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
              remove_action('wp_head',array($wp_thing,'head'),1);
            }
    }
}
```